# how to align vis-line and vis-box left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, vis.js

I need to make `vis-line` bigger (like 10px) and the `vis-box` left 10px as well so that the `vis-line` and `vis-box` can align left correctly just like one vertical line:

```
 .vis-item.vis-line {
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: red;
  }      
  .vis-item.vis-box {
    border-width: 1;
    text-align: left !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-left-width: 10px;
    border-color: red;
  }
```

see the url https://jsfiddle.net/gbdjbdhv/3/
but `vis-line` is 5px left than the `vis-box` left side. I need advice on how to make the `vis-line` and `vis-box` left side align correctly.

Answer (score 0):

vis.js Timeline dynamically sets the position of the box item. The method responsible for horizontally positioning and repositioning the box item, `BoxItem.prototype.repositionX`, doesn't take into account your intended use case. The best place to address this issue is within the vis.js library.

However, setting each box's `left` value to its corresponding `vis-line`'s `left` value may serve as a functional short term solution. This works under the assumption every box has a line AND every line has a box. All items need to be of the box type. Also, `option.align` is no longer necessary - remove `align: 'left'`.

```
function positionBoxes() {

  var leftValues = [];

  // Get the left value for each vis line
  $('.vis-line').each(function() {
    leftValues.push($(this).css('left'));
  });

  // Set the box's line's left value on the box
  $('.vis-box').each(function(index) {
    $(this).css('left', leftValues[index]);
  });
}

// Call positionBoxes anytime the timeline
// repositioned the boxes (window resize, zoom)
timeline.on('changed', positionBoxes)
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dba4ketr/3/

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in correctly positioning the line when using left/right align: it wasn't reckoning with the line width. Will be fixed in the first next release of vis.js.

See https://github.com/almende/vis/pull/1695